# Skin turns blue after long crying

Tags: newborn, health, crying

Yesterday my baby boy cried a lot and he became some kind of blue, I think it's because he was crying for a 3-5 minutes (this doesn't happen before, it's because We had to wake him from sleep :) ), I just wonder is this is a normal behavior, anyway he has a normal skin color, just when he cries he is a little bit of red.

Comment: Please seek expert medical attention ASAP.

Comment: I'm closing this because it is asking for specific medical advice, and that is outside of our scope. For medical considerations, your first resource should be your pediatrician, instead of a group of people on the Internet, no matter how enthusiastic or experienced we may be.

Comment: I understand , is there anything i need to do to this question? Thanks.
P.S.Sorry i want ask that kind of questions anymore, i just want to know is someone had similar problem, that's all, sorry again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Maulik is correct, cyanosis is the term. ***However, cyanosis is [not normal](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003215.htm). You need to take your baby to a Pediatrician, asap.***

> I just wonder is this is a normal behavior,

Babies can have mottled skin, usually as the result of the cold (1). Even a crying baby will inhale large gulps of air, which is why some people are keen to hear a newborn cry.

You mention this occurred when you woke you baby up, it may be possible removing him from the warm environment where he slept, especially if the infant is being undressed or having a nappy change, he may have gotten cold and his skin has become a mottled blue from the cold.  However, this is pure conjecture, as I have no way of saying whether this is normal.

Cyanosis can be the sign of a serious medical condition. I would seek prompt medical advice. Some examples: I have a nephew (now 20) who had cyanosis as a baby, as he had a serious heart condition (requiring surgery), I have had episodes of cyanosis due to a major vein to my heart being totally blocked (requiring surgery). These are just some examples of how serious the causes of cyanosis can be. I also have a condition called Raynaud's phenomenon (2) which cause peripheral cyanosis.

The only time my babies were blue when crying was when they were first born, and that is because they required oxygen, as they were premature. A healthy baby will usually go red with a good crying bout.

> **[Central cyanosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanosis)**   Central cyanosis is often due to a circulatory or ventilatory problem that leads to poor blood oxygenation in the
>   lungs. It develops when arterial saturation drops to ≤85% or ≤75%.
>
> Acute cyanosis can be a result of asphyxiation or choking, and is one
>   of the surest signs that respiration is being blocked.
>
> Central cyanosis may be due to the following causes:
>
> 1. Central Nervous System (impairing normal ventilation):
> 2. Respiratory System:
> 3. Cardiac Disorders:
> 4. Blood:
> 5. Others:
>
> **Peripheral cyanosis**
>   Peripheral cyanosis is the blue tint in fingers
>   or extremities, due to inadequate circulation. The blood reaching the
>   extremities is not oxygen rich and when viewed through the skin a
>   combination of factors can lead to the appearance of a blue color. All
>   factors contributing to central cyanosis can also cause peripheral
>   symptoms to appear, however peripheral cyanosis can be observed
>   without there being heart or lung failures. Small blood vessels may be
>   restricted and can be treated by increasing the normal oxygenation
>   level of the blood.
>
> Peripheral cyanosis may be due to the following causes:
>
> All common causes of central cyanosis Reduced cardiac output (e.g.
>   heart failure, hypovolaemia)
>   Cold exposure (1)
>    Arterial obstruction (e.g.
>   peripheral vascular disease, Raynaud phenomenon (2))
>   Venous obstruction
>   (e.g. deep vein thrombosis)

---

*Now that I have frightened everybody. **This does NOT mean there IS definitely something wrong with your baby.** We cannot see your baby and the color is an interpretation you are giving us.*

Comment: As a counterpoint to your nephew, my cousin was known to literally scream until he passed out (while he was a baby). Today he's a Navy SEAL and pilot. Clearly, his past did not affect his bodily abilities.

Comment: Thanks Skippy for your time and extensive answer, your answer scares me, and i know i need to be careful consider the health, and i will take him to pediatrician again and let you know what was the problem. t didn't happen again and i think he is fine now.

Comment: @PetarA. I am NOT diagnosing your baby, Please note I mentioned if you'd undressed him and that babies do become mottly when cold. I was making a strong response about cyanosis generally. Most babies ARE healthy. BUT I cannot just say, it's OK, when I do not know either way. Be guided by your doctor. Of course you worry, we all worry about our children.. pls let us know how you all get along. Try not to take too much about one person's post on the internet. I am covering a serious topic, that may not be relevant to you. OK?

Comment: OK Skippy, thanks for the help and for your concern, I will take your advice :) cheers

Answer (score 2):

The term used for this condition is 'cyanosis'. It's a bluish discoloration of the skin (and sometimes mucous membranes). The sole reason for this is lack of adequate amount of oxygen.

When the baby cries a lot, the breathing does not happen properly as a result of what cyanosis happen. It's utterly a normal physiological process and you need not worry about it.

He turn red when he cries a bit -that's because while crying the muscles are contracted and they work harder that boosts the blood circulation locally. This is also normal.

Comment: @PetarA. Okay, do visit your pediatrician and let me know the final diagnosis. It seems my answer has been taken vaguely by Skippy. Nevertheless, as a healthcare provider, I give priority to what *first* the patient says. Your question has a clear title - AFTER LONG CRYING. And then the whole picture you presented clarifies rest. I answered that way without scaring you as a father.

Comment: Thanks for not scaring me out, I think that too, pediatrician says that she will keep eye on him ( and that scares me out ), but it doesn't happen again after a few days ago.

Comment: @PetarA. God bless your child but do tell what was *the reason* of that blueish color what you asked and were concerned about.